# Return the smaller vector from List<Vector3>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to return the smaller vector3 from a list of vectors, something like:

```
var positions = new List<Vector3>();

positions.Add(new Vector3(135, 125, 13));
positions.Add(new Vector3(55, 12, 13));
positions.Add(new Vector3(1353, 346, 13));
positions.Add(new Vector3(1442, 979, 134));

private Vector3 SmallerPosition(List<Vector3> positions)
{
    positions.Sort();
    return positions[0];
}

Debug.Log(SmallerPosition(positions));
```

But I know this is not possible, so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: `Sort` does not know by what to sort. By `x`, `y`, `z`, the angle the magnitude or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use linq.

```
positions.OrderBy(v => v.sqrMagnitude).First();
```

Comment: It's perfect, but could you explain me what is happening? I had no idea I could use **sqrMagnitude** to do that.

Comment: You could use `Magnitude`, i.e. the length of the vector as well; however, this requires the square root to be calculated `sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`, while `sqrMagnitude` just calculates `x^2 + y^2 + z^2`, but the order remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by saying `smaller vector` you mean smaller by `magnitude`. In this case, comparing `sqrMagnitude` will be enough and gain us better performance since we are not letting `Math.Sqrt` do its heavy work to calculate the magnitude.

Using LINQ will work fine, but if you are for performance, iterate over manually instead of sorting.

```
private Vector3 SmallerPosition(List<Vector3> positions)
{

    var minVector = positions[0];
    var minSqrMagnitude = minVector.sqrMagnitude;
    for(int i = 1; i < positions.Count; i++)
    {
        var sqrMag = positions[i].sqrMagnitude;
        if (sqrMag < minSqrMagnitude) 
        {    
            minVector = positions[i];
            minSqrMagnitude = sqrMag;
        }
    }

    return minVector;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it was my first attempt indeed, but I didn't know how to compare the different vectors each others, now I know it's not the vector itself, it's the magnitud what we need to compare.

Comment: @LobsangWhite Well, I suggest you to take your time and learn *the math behind* these. It will help you a lot!

Comment: For sure, I've got an ebook of _video game maths_ I'll continue reading